# CodeIgniter PHP Parsing Error unexpected '{', expecting '('

Tags: codeigniter-3, php-parse-error

What's with this **PHP Parsing Error Unexpected '{', expecting '('**

No backtrace, no any other error message, just one line in the controller, that's it -_-

I kept looking for solutions and reading many links related to this.

What could be the reason for the error in my code below..

This **was** my controller code (which was working fine):

```
if (isset($filter) && !empty($search)) {
            $data['users'] = $this->model_search->searchTutor($field, $search);
        }
        elseif (($filter == 'subjName') && !empty($search)) {
            $data['users'] = $this->model_search->searchBySubj($field, $search);
        }
        else {
            $data['users'] = $this->model_search->getlist($field);
        }

        //later i wanted to add a code that will show No Result Found
```

The view file of my page started giving this error **when I added an elseif** statement in my controller (Search.php):

```
if (isset($filter) && !empty($search)) {
            $data['users'] = $this->model_search->searchTutor($field, $search);
        }
        elseif (($filter == 'subjName') && !empty($search)) {
            $data['users'] = $this->model_search->searchBySubj($field, $search);
        }
        //so I added another elseif
        elseif (isset($filter) && empty($search)) {
            $data['users'] = $this->model_search->getlist($field);
        }
        //and put the No Result last
        else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('nores','<div class="alert text-center">No result matched your search.</div>');
        }
```

Is it because of the multiple elseif condition or am I really missing something here? Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
elseif {
```

Your new `elseif` has no condition. When do you expect it to run? You need to add a condition.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out I edited it now.. But why won't it display the flashdata in the view? It's supposed to echo No Result...

Comment: @Distro That appears to be a completely different issue. If it is, you should mark this question as solved, and ask a new question.

Comment: @Distro where you what to see your flashdata?

Comment: @Distro Ya, np. When your ask the new question, make sure to include as many details about what you're trying to do as possible.

Comment: @Hikmat Sijapati I think I'll have to add some other conditions. I echo it in view:
`<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('nores'); ?>`

Comment: @Distro you have just redirect to page  where you want to display flash data.

Comment: @Hikmat Sijapati Yes. Thanks.